# Contact Form 7 in lightbox using Jquery

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress - Woocommerce site I have added a link "Contact/Info" next to the "Add to Cart button" on the product pages. This was done by adding some jquery. The link works great, but I would like to change it to call a contact form 7 form in a lightbox. I am currently linking to the default Contact page on the site.

Code:

`jQuery(function($) {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').after('<a target="_blank" href="/contact-2">Contact / Info</a>');
});`

Reason for wanting the change it is that I have a contact form 7 form setup that tracks the URL it's been sent from. This will only add be of use when the messages will be sent from the product pages of course.

Here's a link to a [product page on my site](https://www.vintagevibes.nl/en/product/danish-modern-smile-coffee-table)

Anybody any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try adding fancybox with link to your contact..? Your contact form url will open in `iframe` visual would be slightly same as per lightbox :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Not sure what you mean exactly but important is that no new page is loaded. Can you elaborate on your suggested solution please?